# Implementing mathematical theorems

Tags: theorem

This is a general design question on implementing math theorems.
I am trying to implement some math theorems, from differential geometry, in a programming language (it doesn't matter which; for simplicity I use the python language, but this should not affect the general ideas.). I can describe the question better with an example.

**Theorem:** Any straight line on a surface of class r>= 2 is an asymptotic curve.

How would be such a theorem implemented. Obviously the function needs a line as an argument and the surface as an argument.

```
def theorem (line, surface): pass
```

Should the function return just true, false, or undecidable? Or should the function return "asymptotic". If we name the function "is-asymptotic", then it should return true, false, or undecidable.

The first thing that the function should check is if the line is straight. Let's don't go into details. Then, it should compute the class of the surface

```
def theorem (line, surface): 
  if not straight(line, surface):
    return "undecidable"
  else:
    if class-of(surface) >= 2:
      ???
```

The above approach drives me to return true/false. On the other hand, if I implement it as a method to a class called line, that asks for all the properties of the given line then it should return a list of properties, including "asymptotic".

Finally, what I did above is to ask for a property of a given line, our argument. The function says nothing about all the other straight lines.

How would you address the whole implementation design of theorems?

Thank you in advance.

PS. In order to further clarify the question in a programming language content, the above question is rephrased as following. Assuming I have an instance "line" of the object "Line". Do I ask the instance if it is asymptotic as in

```
is_asymptotic(line) # returns true/false/undecidable
```

or do I ask for its properties and get a list of properties which includes the asymptotic property, as in

```
line_properties(line) # returns [..., "asymptotic", ...]
```

or on the creation of the instance I set the attribute asymptotic, after checking if it is straight, as in

```
line = Line(surface) # sets line.asymptotic = True
```

Comment: Theorems aren't something you implement. They're something you prove, or you use, but not something you implement.

Comment: I know that. The theorem I mentioned above is proven. And I need to implement it, as a part of a more general math tool. I don't see why you cannot implement them.

Comment: It's very unclear what you want the function to do. Proven theorems are tools, not something that can be "implemented" without context. You can create a function that checks whether a line on a surface is an asymptotic curve, and you can use your theorem as a tool to check it, but "implement a theorem" by itself is nonsensical.

Comment: That's why I give the example. Let me clarify. You have an object line, and an object surface. For this specific example, the design question is: does the implemented function returns true/false/undecidable or does it return "asymptotic". 

I suppose you have implemented the theorem for area of a circle. In this case the formulation of the theorem is more complicated than the circle area.

Comment: But that doesn't have anything to do with theorems. If the purpose of the function is to check whether the line is an asymptotic curve, the function returns either true or false.

Comment: Of course it has to do with theorems. You used the above theorem to get to that conclusion. How would you return either true/false/undecidable, if not by using the above theorem? The question is not whether or not we can implement theorems. We do it all the time, even if you don't know. The question is for this specific example, how would you do it.

Answer (score 0):

use the sympy package.

```
In [153]: from sympy import *
In [154]: x = symbols('x')
In [155]: y = symbols('y')
In [156]: z = symbols('z')
In [157]: p = (x+y)**2
In [158]: p
Out[158]: (x + y)**2
In [159]: q = x**2 + 2*x*y + y**2
In [160]: p == q
Out[160]: False
In [161]: p.expand() == q
Out[161]: True
```

you will likely find 
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Geometry-Module

to be helpful.

good luck!